# Many To Many Relationship WPF Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

i have a model that looks like almost like this (it's a simplified version of the real one):

```
using System;

namespace PTSample
{
    public class Person
    {
        public Person(string name) { Name = name; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Lesson
    {
        public Lesson(DateTime date) { this.Date = date; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    }

    public class Presence
    {
        public Presence(Person p, Lesson l, bool v)
        {
            Person = p;
            Lesson = l;
            Value = v;
        }

        public Person Person { get; set; }
        public Lesson Lesson { get; set; }
        public bool Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

i would like to display this model using the WPF Datagrid or equivalent control.

[image: test]

So that the row shows the the person, the lessons are displayed in the columsn and the boolen "Value" is shown in a checkbox

is this possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You would create a ViewModel class that represents each row in the grid and then bind to a collection of that ViewModel class.

Comment: Can you be more specific? both the rows and colums are not fixed